# JSON and carrierwave iphone problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ios, carrierwave

I've been struggling with this issue for more than a week!

I'm having trouble POSTing images from my iphone to a backend rails server with carrierwave gem configured. Posting through the web form works just fine though, also, posting text from iphone through JSON works as well.

Here is my photo controller:

```
  class PhotosController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @photo = Photo.new(:user_id => params[:user_id])
  end

  def create
    @photo  = current_user.photos.build(params[:photo])
    if @photo.save

      respond_to do |format|
         format.html { flash[:notice] = "Successfully created photo."
         redirect_to @photo.user 
         }
         format.json { 
          render :json => {:action => 'create', :owner => current_user}
        }
      end
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

and here is the objective-c code:

```
UIImage *image  = [UIImage imageNamed:@"moon.png"];
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

    NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://127.0.0.1:3000/photos.json"];
    // setting up the URL to post to

    // setting up the request object now
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];


    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"ipodfile.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    // setting the body of the post to the reqeust
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    // now lets make the connection to the web
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(returnString);
```

the response i'm getting from the server is:

"EOFError (bad content body)"

the objective-c code was tested with a php server and the upload was successful!
so I guess my problem has to do with my rails/carrierwave setup. please help me getting the bloody images out of my iPhone and to my rails server.

your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I still experience this error using rails 3.0.6 Any other idea?

Answer (score 2):

Why not try [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) for the POSTing?

It has a lot of convenience methods to post multipart data, and works really well. That way you could probably rule out problems that might arise from possible errors that occur while you're trying to build the request body manually...

Comment: it was a bug in rails (rack). Thank you anyway :)

Comment: edit/close your question, people won't waste their time on this ;)